# Calculating Time for a Attack on Password Hashes

Tags: hash, password-cracking, rainbow-table

Suppose I have a database containing hashes. Hashes are obtained from password developed from randomly chosen set of 94  characters such that each password size is of 8 characters. So we have 94^8 passwords. Each of the passwords are converted into hashes i.e 94^8 hashes and stored in the database.

Now the attacker gets access to  the hashes and he used pre-computed hashes stored in a rainbow table. How can we calculate the time for finding a match between the hashes stored in the DB and the hashes stored in the rainbow table?

Comment: What type of hash? How big is the rainbow table (same size as the number of hashes?)

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/58254/how-do-we-estimate-the-time-taken-to-crack-a-hash-using-brute-force-techniques or https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/188141/how-to-estimate-the-time-for-a-hacker-to-crack-a-strong-password or https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8607/how-quickly-can-these-password-schemes-really-be-beaten or https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/145369/how-long-will-it-take-to-crack-the-passwords-stolen-in-the-yahoo-hack-announced. For rainbow table info, see this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/379/what-are-rainbow-t

Comment: You do not provide sufficient details. How many hashes has the attack DB and what is the hardware performance of the systems comparing them ?

Answer (score 1):

Hash on the rainbow table: instantaneous.

Bruteforce a hash: depends heavily on the hash type (MD5, SHA, etc), how many rounds, if it's salted or not, hardware used...

94<sup>8</sup> is not that big. A system calculating [100 billion MD5 hashes per second](https://gist.github.com/shahril96/168975e2bc8de49492180ae4f1721294) will run all the possible passwords in about 17 hours. MD5 is bad for this, but the same system will do the same for SHA1 (even salted) in 51 hours, a little more than 2 days.

So unless you know the algorithm used, the size of the salt, and the number of rounds, we cannot possibly know.

Comment: "*Hash on the rainbow table: instantaneous.*" No: it's a trade-off, not magic. I guess this would be the most relevant topic for details: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/379/what-are-rainbow-tables-and-how-are-they-used You probably mean that it's relatively fast to crack if it's in a rainbow table (since nobody would make a rainbow table that is slow enough that you'll give up waiting), but "instantaneous" is too much of a hyperbole to be correct.

Comment: In your case what is the size of password and what is the size of character set?94^8 is 6X10^15 which is slightly bigger than 100 billion i.e. 1X10^14. I have got one calculation which says that 6 character passwords over alphabets from A-Z i.e. 26^6 =3X10^8 takes 3 secs to crack. Based upon that I want to find my answer for 94^8. Hope once you provide me the above information, I can do better calculation.

Comment: "crack" and "lookup in rainbow table" are completely different things.

Comment: OP says "he used pre-computed hashes stored in a rainbow table." That implies the rainbow table is already available, and the time taken to walk it is so small that can be considered instantaneous.

Comment: @user2994783 100 billion passwords per second is the hash rate of the linked gig, not the number of passwords. That is 94^8 that I stated.

Comment: Thanks for removing my confusion. God bless you guys.